# Debian 4.7.0-1-amd64 Kernel Compile Error

Tags: linux-kernel

It has been days trying to harden my OS with grsec. 
I keep having trouble in compiling the linux kernel. I'm following the micahflee guide. However when I reach the step to create the image and start compile the kernel with the command ' fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd kernel_image ' it gives me this error: http://beta.pastee.com/8bcht

How can it say the GCC doesn support if it is updated?

Everything is updated and upgraded. Can anyone point me or clarify me how can I get past this issues?

(I'm using Debian 4.7.0-1-amd64 Sid )

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Apparently, it is ["due to the addition of the gcc plugin infrastructure"](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/6/11/145). If that's the case, you should either disable the `GCC_PLUGINS` kconfig option, or install the appropriate `gcc-*-plugin-dev` package.